# not able to store more than 20 tweets to database using twitter 4j and java

Tags: java, mysql, twitter

Not able to store more than 20 tweets to database using twitter4j and java if I use paging then I am getting duplicate entry for primary key tweet_id after 20 entries

Comment: i have modified my code according to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19230065/4671124

Comment: please put your code inside the guestion