# Reading an input file in java

Tags: java

My input file:

```
/home/gcj/finals
```

I want to have each character after `/`
My approach:

```
StringTokenizer sr = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
      String s = sr.nextToken("/");
                 while(s != null){
                     System.out.println(s);
                     s = sr.nextToken("/");
                 }
```

Output:

```
gcj
finals
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
    at jobs.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:118)
```

Please Help me out. OR if there any better method.

Comment: Do you mean "each character" or "each string"? Each character would be 'h', 'g', 'f'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of while (s != null), use hasMoreTokens().

Answer (score 0):

As the [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) docs explains, you must use the `hasMoreTokens` method to loop instead of comparing next() to null.

```
 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(...);
 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
 }
```

And again, as the docs explains, `split` is a better option to split a String in general.

Finally, since you're trying to read a file line by line, you should check out libraries like [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/), they have what you're looking for in [FileUtils.lineIterator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
for (String s : "/home/gcj/finals".split("/")) {
   System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation of why this is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file, you can take the classes IO, In and `Out` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157632/twitter4j-on-java-query-search-only-gives-me-the-6-most-recent-results/26157821#26157821). Then you can simply invoke `IO.in.readFile(String filename)`.

Hope it helps.

Clemencio Morales Lucas.