# Rate limit issues in Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am attempting to track multiple keyword tweets from twitter. I am using twitter4j 3.0.5 as my third party API. But it always raised  below error. Even though it doesn't capture any details.

```
2015-03-02 09:28:15.224  INFO 2859 --- [ing connection]] twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl              : 420:Returned by the Search and Trends API when you are being rate limited (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting).
Returned by the Streaming API:
 Too many login attempts in a short period of time.
 Running too many copies of the same application authenticating with the same account name.
Exceeded connection limit for user
```

Comment: Well, the error seems obvious beyond obvious to me. What exactly is your question? What do you expect us to do about this?

Comment: i need to  collect tweets with multiple keywords.

Comment: Please show the code

Answer (score 1):

You can instead use streaming API. This will not have any limitations. If the case you need to get old tweets, follow the answer given by **Deniz Ozger** in this link [Is it possible to get more than 100 tweets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887984/is-it-possible-to-get-more-than-100-tweets). It's working.